# What should I change in grub.cfg to boot Chromium OS Lime off of a second internal drive?

Tags: ssd, grub, google-chrome-os

I have Chromium OS Lime installed on my second internal drive (sdb) and can't seem to get it to boot. While it boots off of a USB when I try booting it from the second drive (SSD), it takes me to a `sh:grub>` command line. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Here's the grub.cfg:**

```
set default=0
set timeout=2

# NOTE: These magic grub variables are a Chrome OS hack. They are not portable.

menuentry "local image A" {
  linux $grubpartA/boot/vmlinuz quiet console=tty2 init=/sbin/init boot=local rootwait ro noresume noswap loglevel=1 noinitrd i915.modeset=1 cros_efi root=/dev/$linuxpartA
}

menuentry "local image B" {
  linux $grubpartB/boot/vmlinuz quiet console=tty2 init=/sbin/init boot=local rootwait ro noresume noswap loglevel=1 noinitrd i915.modeset=1 cros_efi root=/dev/$linuxpartB
}

menuentry "verified image A" {
  linux $grubpartA/boot/vmlinuz quiet console=tty2 init=/sbin/init boot=local rootwait ro noresume noswap loglevel=1 noinitrd dm_verity.error_behavior=2 dm_verity.max_bios=1024 dm_verity.dev_wait=0 i915.modeset=1 cros_efi root=/dev/dm-0 dm=\"vroot none ro,0 1740800 verity payload=PARTUUID=F11EE421-4B7A-6B45-999A-0C685CA171AF hashtree=PARTUUID=F11EE421-4B7A-6B45-999A-0C685CA171AF hashstart=1740800 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=0001ede5fb50caae1b43d0526d23ff0cdbcea6a3 salt=51a3c604a2e8e4d4901f2d14aab6d753af2730ae47deac39c5d012dee47fd6b0\"
}

menuentry "verified image B" {
  linux $grubpartB/boot/vmlinuz quiet console=tty2 init=/sbin/init boot=local rootwait ro noresume noswap loglevel=1 noinitrd dm_verity.error_behavior=2 dm_verity.max_bios=1024 dm_verity.dev_wait=0 i915.modeset=1 cros_efi root=/dev/dm-0 dm=\"DMTABLEB\"
}

# FIXME: usb doesn't support verified boot for now
menuentry "Alternate USB Boot" {
  linux (hd0,3)/boot/vmlinuz quiet console=tty2 init=/sbin/init boot=local rootwait ro noresume noswap loglevel=1 noinitrd root=/dev/sdb3 i915.modeset=1 cros_efi
}
```

Here's the partition layout:

[image]

The boot partition is sbd12, the 17 MB FAT partition. H-STATE is sbd1, and C-ROOT is sbd3.

Here's what the three partitions contain:

[image]

3CCE-5799 is the 17 MB FAT partition. I'm not sure how much these help though.

Comment: What is partition number on sdb is the vmlinuz kernel (boot partition), and what partition is the system root (possibly the same).  The grub line says /dev/sdb3, is that right for root and boot?

Comment: @Paul: It's updated to (hopefully) show/tell you the correct partitions for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the grub device map is sane, and sda maps to hd0 and sdb is hd1, this entry in grub should work:

```
menuentry "Chrome OS SSD" {
  linux (hd1,3)/boot/vmlinuz quiet console=tty2 init=/sbin/init boot=local rootwait ro     noresume noswap loglevel=1 noinitrd root=/dev/sdb3 i915.modeset=1 cros_efi
}
```

From the file layouts provided, it looks like everything is in c-root, so that should be fine.  The only problem with is was that it was trying too load the kernel from your hard disk.  Make sure the `/boot/vmlinuz` part is right by looking in c-root into /boot and making sure it is present.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. Would I need to 'update' grub or do you need to check some other files?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what happens?  Is vmlinuz in /boot on /dev/sdb3 ?

Comment: Yeah, the vmlinuz is there. When I boot it takes me to a screen that has a sh:grub> command line/terminal.

Comment: If you hit 'e' on the entry when the grub menu shows up you should be able to see that it has picked up the right .cfg

Comment: Hang on, is that grub.cfg the entire thing, I assumed it was an excerpt?  Where did it come from?  Is it the one from the machine you are booting?

Comment: There isn't even a grub menu. It just goes straight to the sh:grub> command line. And yes, that's the entire grub.cfg. And it is the one from the machine that I'm trying to boot. Also, [this](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-os-reviews/msg/d3d586435d36fb1a?pli=1) **might** help.

Comment: How are you able to boot the machine with that grub.cfg - are you putting the ssd into another machine to make changes?

Comment: No, this machine has an SSD and a HDD. I have Ubuntu and Windows on the HDD and I'm mounting and editing it from Ubuntu.

Comment: Aaah.  You should be able to run `upgrade-grub` from Ubuntu and have it detect and automatically create the entry for chrome in its own grub.cfg, so leave the hdd as the boot drive.